# Need some hints and optimization tips

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

> Write a function called password_check. password_check should take as input a single string. It should return a boolean: True if the password is a valid password according to the rules below, False if it is not. A string is a valid password if it meets ALL the following conditions:
>
> - It must be at least 8 characters long.
> - It must contain at least one character from each of the following categories: capital letters, lower-case letters,numbers, and punctuation. For punctuation, the following punctuation marks are acceptable: !@#$%&()-_[]{};':",./<>?
> - It may not contain any characters that do not fit into the four categories above. This includes any punctuation marks not listed in the bullet point above, spaces, and any other character.

One of the way for solving this problem:

```
def password_check(as_string):
    uppercase = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    lowercase = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    punctuation = ["!","@","#","$","%","&","(",")","-","_","[","]","{","}",";","'",":",",",".","/","<",">","?"]
    number = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9", "0"]
    cup = 0
    low = 0
    num = 0
    punc = 0
    for i in as_string:
        if i in uppercase:
            cup+=1
        elif i in lowercase:
            low+=1
        elif i in number:
            num+=1
        elif i in punctuation:
            punc+=1
    return (cup>=1) and (low>=1) and (num>=1) and (punc>=1) and len(as_string)>=8
print(password_check("tHIs1sag00d.p4ssw0rd."))
print(password_check("3@t7ENZ((T"))
print(password_check("2.shOrt"))
print(password_check("all.l0wer.case"))
print(password_check("inv4l1d CH4R4CTERS~"))
```

Are there any optimization tips, maybe without creating lists...?
Thanks.

Comment: Regular expressions.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Since it seems you have working code and are looking for general improvements, this appears to more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) – be sure to check their [question guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can do this by Using Regex Expressions

```
import re
def password_check(Str):
    #Regex Match
    #Check Both Case Alphabets,Numbers And Special Cases U Mentioned
    #{8,} Indicates At Least 8
    #Full Match Matches Entire Pattern
    #Few Symbols Has special meaning in regex to bypass that we add "\" before it 
    if re.fullmatch(r'[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%,-^&+_\':=\;.<?>\\{\}\)\(\[\]]{8,}', Str):
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
print(password_check("tHIs1sag00d.p4ssw0rd."))
print(password_check("3@t7ENZ((T"))
print(password_check("2.shOrt"))
print(password_check("all.l0wer.case"))
print(password_check("inv4l1d CH4R4CTERS~"))
```